# CAShapeLayer's frame and bounds properties are 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(50, 50);
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(100, 100);

UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint:startPoint];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:endPoint];

layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
//layer.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
layer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
layer.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
layer.fillColor = nil;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(layer.bounds));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(layer.frame));
```

The Log Message that i get is 0,0 for both frame and bound yet the layer is drawn on the Screen.

I am confused on how it is possible that a layer can be drawn on screen in spite of having 0 on both bounds and frames. I though every view or layer needed to have these properties set in order to be displayed on screen.